# makefile read reused variable inside recipe

Tags: makefile

In trying to implement [nonrecursive make](http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html), I have a Rules.mk which looks like:

```
############
# Enter Stack
############
sp              := $(sp).x
dirstack_$(sp)  := $(d)
d               := $(dir)

.. setup things like OBJECTS_$(d), DEPS_$(d), TARGET_$(d), etc ...

############
# Exit Stack
############
-include        $(DEPS_$(d))
d               := $(dirstack_$(sp))
sp              := $(basename $(sp))
```

One of the variables I wanted to set was:

```
INCLUDE_PATH_$(d) := -Isomething -Isomething/else ...
```

To be used in the compilation rule:

```
$(OBJDIR_$(d))/%.o : $(d)/%.cpp $(OBJDIR_$(d))/%.d
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH_$(d)) -o $@ -c $<
```

But this doesn't work - `$(INCLUDE_PATH_$(d))` doesn't get expanded until later - when `$(d)` is no longer has the value I need it to have in order for this to work. What's the way for me to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a target-specific variable

```
$(OBJDIR_$d)/%.o : INCLUDES := $(INCLUDE_PATH_$d)
$(OBJDIR_$d)/%.o : $d/%.cpp $(OBJDIR_$d)/%.d
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<
```

The following is perhaps more standard / flexible (assuming `CPPFLAGS` isn't set to recursively expand) although it depends on your needs

```
$(OBJDIR_$d)/%.o : CPPFLAGS += $(INCLUDE_PATH_$d)
$(OBJDIR_$d)/%.o : $d/%.cpp $(OBJDIR_$d)/%.d
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```